# Why does lambda auto& parameter choose const overload?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, generic-lambda

I'm trying to implement a class which wraps an arbitrary type and a mutex. To access the wrapped data, one needs to pass a function object as parameter of the `locked` method. The wrapper class will then pass the wrapped data as parameter to this function object.

I'd like my wrapper class to work with const & non-const, so I tried the following

```
#include <mutex>
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename Mutex = std::mutex>
class   Mutexed
{
private:
    T m_data;
    mutable Mutex m_mutex;

public:
    using type = T;
    using mutex_type = Mutex;

public:
    explicit Mutexed() = default;

    template<typename... Args>
    explicit Mutexed(Args&&... args)
        : m_data{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}

    template<typename F>
    auto locked(F&& f) -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(m_data)) {
        std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return std::forward<F>(f)(m_data);
    }

    template<typename F>
    auto locked(F&& f) const -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(m_data)) {
        std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return std::forward<F>(f)(m_data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Mutexed<std::string> str{"Foo"};

    str.locked([](auto &s) { /* this doesn't compile */
        s = "Bar";
    });

    str.locked([](std::string& s) { /* this compiles fine */
        s = "Baz";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

The first `locked` call with the generic lambda fails to compile with the following error

```
/home/foo/tests/lamdba_auto_const/lambda_auto_const/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘main()::<lambda(auto:1&)> [with auto:1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
/home/foo/tests/lamdba_auto_const/lambda_auto_const/main.cpp:30:60:   required by substitution of ‘template<class F> decltype (forward<F>(f)(((const Mutexed<T, Mutex>*)this)->Mutexed<T, Mutex>::m_data)) Mutexed<T, Mutex>::locked(F&&) const [with F = main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>]’
/home/foo/tests/lamdba_auto_const/lambda_auto_const/main.cpp:42:6:   required from here
/home/foo/tests/lamdba_auto_const/lambda_auto_const/main.cpp:41:11: error: passing ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         s = "Bar";
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/mutex:38,
                 from /home/foo/tests/lamdba_auto_const/lambda_auto_const/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:558:7: note:   in call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
```

But the second call with the `std::string&` parameter is fine.

Why is that ? And is there a way to make it work as expected while using a generic lambda ?

Comment: @YSC A lambda, generic or otherwise, is a class, not a class template. `F` is happily resolved to that class. The fact that the class has member templates is irrelevant at that point.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a problem fundamentally with what happens with SFINAE-unfriendly callables. For more reference, check out [P0826](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0826r0.html).

The problem is, when you call this:

```
 str.locked([](auto &s) { s = "Bar"; });
```

We have *two* overloads of `locked` and we have to try both. The non-`const` overload works fine. But the `const` one – even if it won't be selected by overload resolution anyway – still has to be instantiated (it's a generic lambda, so to figure out what `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(m_data))` might be you have to instantiate it) and that instantiation fails within the body of the lambda. The body is outside of the immediate context, so it's not a substitution failure – it's a hard error.

When you call this:

```
str.locked([](std::string& s) { s = "Bar"; });
```

We don't need to look at the body at all during the whole process of overload resolution – we can simply reject at the call site (since you can't pass a `const string` into a `string&`).

There's not really a solution to this problem in the language today – you basically have to add constraints on your lambda to ensure that the instantiation failure happens in the immediate context of substitution rather than in the body. Something like:

```
str.locked([](auto &s) -> void {
    s = "Bar";
});
```

Note that we don't need to make this SFINAE-friendly - we just need to ensure that we can determine the return type without instantiating the body.

---

A more thorough language solution would have been to allow for "Deducing `this`" (see [the section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0847r2.html#sfinae-friendly-callables) in the paper about this specific problem). But that won't be in C++20.

Comment: Well this is a shame.  +1 as this had me really scratching my head.  I couldn't figure out why it was calling the const version, and as you point out it really isn't, it just has to check, and the check results in a hard error.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Could you elaborate on "_The body is outside of the immediate context"_ a bit though? (I'm unclear of what exactly is the immediate context)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the workaround. It works, but since it's more verbose than writing the type, I'll do that instead of using `auto` for this case. I'll check out the paper too.

Comment: Would it work if you took the parameter as an `auto&&` parameter (though then you can pass rvalues, which you don't really want to allow)?

Comment: @NicolBolas No, same problem. You have to structure the lambda in such a way that the overload gets rejected while instantiating the call operator, not the body.

Comment: @Barry, I can see in the beginning of your paper that this case can be solved with a friended-templated-non-member function.

Comment: @Unda Yeah, if you want to call it like `locked(str, []{...})` instead. Just changes the syntax.

Comment: @Barry, I think it's a great alternative until P0826 makes it to the standard: it works with `auto&` as one could expect and it avoids code duplication.

Comment: @Unda You mean P0847?

Comment: @Barry, Right, I thought you mentioned the same paper twice in your answer, my mistake.

Comment: The reason why we have to instantiate the body of the lambda at O/R time is because of the deduced return type. Explicitly specifying `-> void` on the lambda is sufficient; there's no need to make it fully SFINAE-correct.

Comment: @T.C. Right you are - was conflating two entirely unrelated things.

Comment: @T.C. Why does it instantiate the lambda even though the return type doesn't depend on the lambda parameter type at all? It's always void.

Comment: @Johannes You only know it's always void by instantiating it. Unless you're suggesting special casing lexically having no `return` statements, which is pretty specific.

Comment: @Barry compilers do a lot of syntactic special casings in templates to avoid users the burden of writing `typename`. Why not do it for return-types? If in the lambda we write `return e`, and whether it's an `int e;` previously declared or an `void()`-expression, then the compiler can mark the template's return type as non-dependent and deduce it right away to that type.